# How to use Paperclip gem with Trestle gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, paperclip

So, I am using Trestle gem for my admin panel [Trestle GitHub](https://github.com/TrestleAdmin/trestle).

And I am using Paperclip gem for uploading images [PaperClip GitHub](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

Now, I have a website which shows products for some grocery store. And products are added trough admin panel with Trestle. It was working great with adding name, price, description etc. but when I add image field with Paperclip gem I can't upload image as input, it is just text input. Here is image of admin panel:
[Admin Panel Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJWhP.png)

Image input field is at bottom so it cannot be seen in picture. But it looks the same like Name field. It's just text input with no option to upload image.
Not what should I do in order to upload images via Admin panel from Trestle.

Comment: You have to use a `file_field` on the form. I think you'll have to add `multipart: true` to the form too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but Paperclip has been deprecated since I asked this question

Answer (score 0):

Since there is ActiveStorage now, the solution would be to use the [trest-active-storage](https://github.com/richardvenneman/trestle-active_storage) gem:

1.) Update your `Gemfile`

```rb
# /Gemfile.rb
gem 'trestle'
gem 'trestle-active_storage'
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'
gem 'poppler' # # Previews of PDFs
```

2.) Then use `active_storage_field` in your `form`s:

```rb
form do |ifu|
  concat Trestle::Form::Automatic.new(admin).render(self, ifu)
  active_storage_field :files # if :files is your `has_one|many_attached` field
end
```